# If y=4 and z=10, then what are the set of integers modulo z?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

let's consider x = k.z +y then how can we define the set of integers modulo z? and what does set of integers modulo z mean?

I am a programmer and I try to understand these things so could any body help me.

I found this example

The Set Of Integers Modulo P
The set:

> Zp={0,1,2,...,p−1}(1) Is called the set of integers modulo p (or mod p
>   for short). It is a set that contains Integers from 0 up until p−1.
>
> Example: Z10={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}

but I do not know why the call that set as `set of integers modulo p`

Comment: Doing addition, subtraction, or multiplication modulo $z$ means doing the operation the usual way, then dividing by $z$, throwing away the quotient, and reporting only the remainder. For example, doing $6\times7$ modulo $10$, you do $6\times7=42$, $42$ divided by $10$ is $4$, remainder $2$, so the answer is $2$.

Comment: There are probably thousands of existing resources online about the definition of modulo, including Wikipedia. Have you looked at any of them?

Comment: I have edited my question it could be clearer now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put, to consider the integers modulo $z$ is to take the entire set of integers $\{0,-1,1,-2,2,\cdots\}$, divide everything by $z$, and consider only the remainders.

Therefore "the set integers modulo $z$" is the set of all possible remainders upon division by $z$, which is $\{0,1,\cdots,z-1\}$.

Is this clear?

Comment: thanx a lot....